# GWT assembly of the RPC Serialization White List Entrys

Tags: gwt, serialization, whitelist

i want, for test engineering reasons, to add some entrys to the GWT RPC Serialization List. Unfortunately i found no real documentation on how this entrys are build. So far i see them like this:

```
classname, bool, bool, bool, bool, classname(repeat), Serialization UID, Serialization UID(repeat)
```

The Classname and the UID ist clear so far. But what meaning do the four boolean values have? Did i miss them in the gwt documentation?

Regards
Makenshi

Comment: As per SerializationPolicyLoader class, the boolean fields are for representing field serializable, instant serializable, field deserializable, instant deserializable.

Comment: Thank you, this was the point i was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As per SerializationPolicyLoader class, the boolean fields are for
>   representing field serializable, instant serializable, field
>   deserializable, instant deserializable.
>   -Seshagiri

That was the answer i was looking for.
Thanks to Seshagiri.